# Linux Python: inet, subnet, gateway, DNS - best way to change these

Tags: linux, python-3.x

In my Python program (running on a Rasbian Pi, Linux), I'm changing values like the inet and the subnet with code like this:

```
os.system('sudo ifconfig eth1 %s netmask %s' % (self.controller.internet_inet_value.get(), self.controller.internet_mask_value.get()))
```

**I'm NOT using this, though maybe I should...:**

```
                '''subprocess.Popen(['sudo', 'ifconfig', 'eth1', '%s' % self.controller.internet_inet_value.get(),
                                  'netmask', '%s' % self.controller.internet_mask_value.get()])'''
```

---

for gateway I'm using:

```
gw_obj = subprocess.check_output(['sudo', 'route', 'add', 'default', 'gw', '%s' % self.controller.internet_default_gateway_value.get()]) #, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True
                                self.controller.internet_default_gateway_value2.set(self.controller.internet_default_gateway_value.get())
```

---

and my DNS values go something like this:

```
os.system('sudo ifconfig eth1 dns-nameservers %s %s %s' % (local_dns_var, local_dns_var2, local_dns_var3))
```

QUESTION: Is there a better way of doing this? These methods *sort of* work but I'm sure there must be a better way! I'd rather change these values at a python level instead of dipping into the OS. (These bits of code are obviously isolated from the rest).

Comment: Do you start your python program as root? There are some interfaces to change network settings programmatically, but it is much easier to use `ifconfig` or `ip` commands to do their job (if your code works and solves the task, it is already good enough). (Or just do correct setup of /etc/ files which stores network settings.)

Comment: No, I didn't use root. I guess the code does work so I guess it's fine. Thanks, Osgx!

Comment: When your python program is not root, it should use some kind of sudo & separate program to make changes to system settings like network settings. So, even when you have password-less sudo, you should fork to run sudo and other process as root. And in this case it is easier to use already  written `ifconfig`/`ip` utils than rewrite them with python.